# Adobe Air with HTML DOM

Tags: air, dom

How do I use Adobe Air with HTML DOM?

```
"<input type="text" class="inputtext" name="myemail" id="email" tabindex="1">"
```

I tried

1. document.getElementById('email').value
   = "111@domain.com";
2. document.getElementById('myemail').value
   = "111@domain.com";

It doesn't work

**ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property getElementById not found on Main and there is no default value.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your javascript in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //do stuff here
});
```